# GoogleCredential.Builder() cannot be resolved

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am developing a Service Account application to obtain Token for accessing downstream services. However, I am facing an issue with compilation. Eclipse prompts an error "**The type com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**". Code snippet below:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;


public class AppMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId("SOMETHING@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
      .setServiceAccountScopes(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
      .build();
}
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: almost certainly a problem with your library versions. Make sure you have the latest versions, and then don't be surprised if sample code doesn't work because it rarely gets updated after breaking changes in the library.

Comment: Thanks! you rightly said it was an issue with version

Comment: Hi! I am facing similar problem, which library are you using?

Comment: I replaced latest version of jackson core with version 1.9.11 and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this error with overriding google-api-client dependency to this -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved above issue and getting token by adding one more jar in library "google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar". Below is code snippet

```
GoogleCredential googleCredentials = GoogleCredential.fromStream(serviceAccount);
GoogleCredential scoped = googleCredentials.createScoped(
Arrays.asList(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"    
            )
    );
scoped.refreshToken();
String token = scoped.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: google-oauth-client-x.xx.x.jar also resolved my issue. You might need com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory instead of  ..jackson.JacksonFactory